# TFS to VSTS post migration user cleanup

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

several months ago i migrated my on-prem TFS server to VSTS, and it worked great except for migrating users.  No problem, i created new users that have been in use and people are using the VSTS instance w/out issues.

My question is that our VSTS server still has all this historical data for users that are now invalid.  is there a way to clean them up?  Or merge an old user with the new/current one?  Migration is already done, i can't 'redo' it, but is there anything i can do after the fact?

Answer (score 0):

No. The historical data is just that -- historical. It's necessary to maintain history. If you have a work item assigned to Bob, and you delete Bob, then who is that work item supposed to show as the assignee? If that work item shouldn't be assigned to Bob anymore, then reassign it to the correct person.

Comment: well, what you say makes sense for the most part, but it ignores the fact that mapping users from one identity to another does exist on the TFS to VSTS migration ( https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/78 ) .  All i'm asking is 'since this wasn't done correctly during migration, is there any way to do the same Post migration?